# p(y)=x^3-5 intersecting x axis

Tags: functions, polynomials

In how many points does the graph of polynomial $$p(y) =x^3-5$$ meets the x-axis? **It is $p(y)$ and not $p(x)$**. so I am doubtful.
Will this equation intersect x-axis at all?
or is this invalid?

Comment: $p(y)$ does not make sense , when it is dependent only on $x$

Comment: What do you finally answer?

Comment: It should be $p(x)$ or $y$, but not $p(y)$

Comment: So you say equation is invalid

Comment: Or the answer is 0

Comment: I would consider it invalid , if there is no more context. Probably it is just a typo.

Comment: Additionally, not the equation intersects the $x$-axis, but the graph of the function $p(x)=x^3-5$ does. $p(x)=x^3-5$ is not an equation. $x^3-5=0$ is the equation which must be solved to find the roots.

Comment: @vrugtehagel True, but I have great doubts that this is the intended exercise.

Comment: Like this came in a test so I had no choice other than writing 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p(y) =x^3-5$$ does not make sense unless $P(y)$ is defined first.

If the independent variable is y, then why it is defined as a function of x ?

If $P(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ then it should have been defined.

For example if   $$p(y) =y^2+1 $$ then $$ y^2+1 =x^3-5$$ is an equation to be solved for $y=0$ to find x-intercepts.